# Mysql Parent id child id relation

Tags: mysql

Here is my table

```
id parent_key field key status
1  0          f1    fk1  1
2  0          f2    fk2  0
3  fk2        f3    fk3  1
4  fk3        f4    fk4  1
5  0          f5    fk5  1
6  fk5        f6    fk6  1
7  fk6        f7    fk7  1
8  fk7        f8    fk8  0
9  fk8        f9    fk9  1
```

Now I want following data using mysql query

```
id parent_key field key status
1  0          f1    fk1  1
5  0          f5    fk5  1
6  fk5        f6    fk6  1
7  fk6        f7    fk7  1
```

Look if parent row status is 0 then all the corresponding child field will not be considered.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming table name and column. Try this simple query

```
SELECT parent.id,parent.parent_key,parent.field,parent.status FROM parent   
as parent INNER JOIN child as child ON parent.id=child.id WHERE   
parent.status!=0
```

define columns which are required.

Comment: I thought of this too, but this only fetch the direct children of a parent, not the whole recursive children "tree" below a parent (until a leaf or status=0 has been reached)

Comment: not clear. also in sample data you haven't consider all the recored whose status is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Create Table Statement.

```
create table test (
  id int, 
  parent_key varchar(10),
  field varchar(10), 
  key1 varchar(10),
  status int
);
```

Insert query statement.

```
insert into test values (1,'0'  ,'f1','fk1',1);
insert into test values (2,'0'  ,'f2','fk2',0);
insert into test values (3,'fk2','f3','fk3',1);
insert into test values (4,'fk3','f4','fk4',1);
insert into test values (5,'0','f5','fk5',1);
insert into test values (6,'fk5','f6','fk6',1);
insert into test values (7,'fk6','f7','fk7',1);
insert into test values (8,'fk7','f8','fk8',0);
insert into test values (9,'fk8','f9','fk9',1);
```

Query:

```
set @status0 = ( select group_concat(key1) from test where status = 0);

select * from 
( select *, 
 if(find_in_set(parent_key,@status0) > 0, @status0 := concat(@status0,',',key1),@status0 ) as check_column
from test ) a 
where 
find_in_set(key1,check_column ) = 0
```

Explanation:

1. Find all key1 having status = 0 and store in @status0.
2. Find all parent key and add it to @status0 variable. See subquery.
3. We have all the key1 which needs to removed from final query.
4. Use find_in_set(key1,check_column ) = 0 condition to
   remove those data.

Comment: Is this helpful to you ?